# VNC viewer on Windows 8 host cannot connect to VNC server, while viewer on Mac OS can

Tags: windows-8, vnc

Problem: I cannot connect to a VNC server when using a VNC viewer on a Windows 8 machine. Co-workers using viewers on Macs do not experience this problem.  The VNC server is on a machine running Ubuntu 14.04.

Other details: 
(1) This problem has been replicated by another Windows user.
(2) I cannot connect using either the RealVNC or TightVNC viewers. 
(3) This was not a problem in the past (as in, more than a year ago).  I am not sure if the problem is a change in Windows, or something else.
(4) When I attempt to connect using RealVNC, the error is "Timed out waiting for a response from the host computer." 
(5) For TightVNC, the error is "Connection timed out."

Any ideas of what to try next?

Comment: Are the Windows systems and Macs on the same [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnet)? I.e., could there be a firewall or some other network device between the Windows systems and the VNC server that doesn't lie in the network path between the Macs and the VNC server?  Does the VNC server, or any firewall before it and the other systems, restrict access by IP address. I.e., have you eliminated the possibility that firewall rules permit connectivity from the IP addresses of the Macs, but not other systems?

Comment: I *think* this explanation is unlikely, because I got the impression that one of my co-workers has tested this out with both a Mac and a PC from within the same office.  I should confirm that, though.  I only own a PC, so I can't run such a test myself.  If there is a way I can check the firewall rules on the server myself, I could look into that (I can access via ssh, just not VNC).

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: No, I never did -- I'm open to new ideas if anyone has them.

Answer (score 1):

I also met this problem. My problem is that I  have vpn opened, I think the vnc viewer tried to link the server through the vpn. After I close vpn, it connect the server successfully. 
By the way, i have only 2 pc connected with a switch. one is centos 7 and the other is win10. hope this will help you.